# Nodejs calling controller from controller give TypeError: res.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

How come it cannot see the **res** part of my calling function?

Here is my calling function **frontpageController.js**

```
exports.getFrontpage = function(req, res) {

    var priceController = require('./priceController');
    var priceModel = require('../models/priceModel');
    var priceTable = mongoose.model('priceModel');
    var callPriceController = function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        priceController.getPrice (
        { "body": { "propertyID": "WAT-606" } }
        ,function(err, data) {
                console.log("HELLO!!! ");
            if (!err) {
                console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            } else {
                console.log("ERR: " + err);
            };
        });
    })};

    callPriceController()
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("getFrontpage ERR: " + err);
            //res.json({error:true,err});
        })
    }
```

Here is the controller that I want to call **getData**

```
exports.getPrice = function(req, res){

    // 
    // Validate the data we get from router
    // 
    console.log("priceController received: " + JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4));
    res.json({error:false,test:"hello from getPrice"});
}
```

And here is the console log:

```
GET /frontpageRoute/getFrontpage - - ms - -
priceController received: {
    "propertyID": "WAT-606"
}
getFrontpage ERR: TypeError: res.json is not a function
```

Here is the getPrice router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var priceController = require('../controllers/priceController');

router.post('/getPrice', function(req, res) {
    priceController.getPrice(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the frontpage router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var frontpageController = require('../controllers/frontpageController');

router.get('/getFrontpage', function(req, res) {
    frontpageController.getFrontpage(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what does `console.log(res)` output?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to call `getData` and get the result `{error:false,test:"hello from getData"}`back

Comment: @JeremyThille I never get a result - it jumps directly to the `catch` and gives the error `TypeError: res.json is not a function` when it reach the `res.json({error:false,test:"hello from getData"});`

Comment: But your controller doesn't call `getData`, it calls `getPrice`... What am I missing?

Comment: @JeremyThille Sorryyyy heheh I was trying to make the code look as simple as possible for stackoverflow.  Forgot to change the name :-D  - I updated the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `getPrice(req, res)` expects `req`and `res`, you have to pass it when you call `getPrice`. Update your **frontpageController.js** to this and see if it works -

```
exports.getFrontpage = function(req, res) {

var priceController = require('./priceController');
var priceModel = require('../models/priceModel');
var priceTable = mongoose.model('priceModel');
var callPriceController = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    priceController.getPrice ({ "body": { "propertyID": "WAT-606" } }, res,
    ,function(err, data) {
            console.log("HELLO!!! ");
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        } else {
            console.log("ERR: " + err);
        };
    });
})};

callPriceController()
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("getFrontpage ERR: " + err);
        //res.json({error:true,err});
    })
}
```

Comment: YES!!!!!  Ohh yes yes yes!! That was it!! - So simple yet so not logical in my head for some reason :-D  Ohhh thank you SO MUCH Manjo!!  I spent 8 hours on this and all it took was `req, res,` - and it makes sense actually when I see it now.

Comment: I was working on MEAN stack last year on a rental project, so it was easy to figure out this one, happy to help.. :)

Comment: That's what I was trying to say......... You were not passing the correct `req` and `res`, but an object and a function

Comment: @JeremyThille yes and thank you so much for helping me as well!!

Comment: I'm frustrated because I was so close :)

Comment: @JeremyThille yes, Jeremy I just saw your answer, you have explained in details what I answered in 2 lines, I think that is where torbenrudgaard may have lost in details regarding the solution. :)

Comment: @ManojSalvi can you make one small change to your answer (I tried but "edit queue is full?!?!".  Here:  `priceController.getPrice (
    { "body": { "propertyID": "WAT-606" } },
     res,function(err, data) {`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand.. "can you make one small change to your answer" ?????

Comment: @torbenrudgaard ok, I edited the answer the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
callGetData()
.catch(err => {
    console.log("ERR: " + err);
    res.json({error:true,err})
}
```

**res is not defined in this scope that's why you are getting this error**

Comment: Actually it is, I just cut all the rest of the code away.  The `callGetData`controller starts with a `exports.getMyData = function(req, res) {`

Comment: @Vikash I'm not sure about that. If `res` was undefined, the error would be `res is undefined`or `Cannot resolve function json of undefined`.

Comment: @JeremyThille exactly and the error is from the getData function, not from the caller.

Comment: @JeremyThille it is almost like the res part is not parsed from the caller to the getData. Only the req part is parsed.

Comment: I believe I understand what's going on, but first please confirm that you are mistakenly calling `myController.getPrice` instead of, as you state in your question, `myController.getData`?

Comment: try changing that line to res.status(404).json({error:false,test:"hello from getData"});

Comment: @VikashKumar gives the same result im afraid :-(

Comment: @JeremyThille yes now I am calling getPrice - the other one was just an example.  `priceController.getPrice (`

Comment: @JeremyThille I just dont understand why `console.log("HELLO!!! ");`is not shown....

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what's going on here.

You're calling `myController.getData`, right? However, this function is defined as such :

```
exports.getData = function(req, res){ }
```

So it's expecting two arguments : `req` and `res`.

But look what you're passing to it : the first argument is `{ "test": "TestData" }`and the second is `function(err, data) {...}`

So, in getData :

```
req == { "test": "TestData" }
res == function(req, res){...}
```

So, `res` is defined, but absolutely not what you're expecting it to be. And indeed, `res.json` is not a function.

I think `getPrice` should be defined this way :

```
exports.getPrice = function(req, callback){       
    callback( null, {error:false, test:"hello from getPrice"});
}
```

So now, back to your promise, you get `err==null` and the correct data.

Comment: Ouuuu!!!!  Thats right!!!...      Ok let me update the question with the real code, cause the error is not in the place I thought it was.  But I think you are on to something there.  Now I just need to find out how to fix it.

Comment: can you have a look now?  This is the original code.  And the error is in the caller, so it probably have something to do with what you say.  I just dont know how to make the call correctly.

Comment: Basically it's still the same problem. You're still passing `function(err, data) { }` as `res`. But actually, why do you need `res` at all in `getData`? That's not where you reply to the browser, is it? Don't you just need to `return(null, data)` instead of replying with `res`? I'm lost in your code :) –

Comment: I got a lot of nodejs controllers who get different things from MongoDB.  So Instead of having Angular call the getPrice controller 20 times, I wanted to have one nodejs controller that call getPrice 20 times and then returns the entire result.  And it kind of works, getPrice gets the data but I just cant get it back.

Comment: I tried your getPrice example but get a `"req is not defined"` error.

Comment: I added the routers just in case - but I cant see anything wrong there either

Comment: Ok I tried something new... `app.post('/getPrice',{ "body": { "propertyID": "WAT-606" } }` which gave me the error `Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]` so something is coming back.